# Theming Android ActionBar: Change TabBar Background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-tabs, android-actionbar-compat

I followed [this Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) to style my ActionBar. I use fixed [tabs](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) in my app so I want to theme the tabs too.
(Note: I'm using the appcompat theme to ensure some backwards compatibility)

So I used

```
<style
    name="CustomTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item>
</style>
```

as my theme.

I set the ActionBar background without problems, but then I tried theming the tabs with:

```
<style
    name="CustomActionBarTabs"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView" >

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/customtheme_actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/customtheme_actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

The background points to a [StateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) where I set different drawables for different contexts, which works kind of as expected. Except it works *just* for the tabs. Not for the ActionBar.

The separator and the background of the tab bar is not themed.
How can I theme those ? (The grey part)

[image: example image]

### Theme Creation Guidelines

I wonder if there are any guidelines for creating a theme that *looks good* ?
(good = similar to default theme, so the app fits into the android ecosystem)

[image: default theme image]

Because If you look closely at the default themes you can see a small line at the bottom of the ActionBar drawable. (The part which is light green in my theme)
There may be other things which you should consider when creating a theme that looks similar to the default themes, so it would be nice to some guideline.

Also: Should the TabBar always be darker than the ActionBar ?
(If so, how much darker?)

How much brighter/darker than the ActionBar color should the image color (like the color of the overflow button in the image) be ?

Thanks in advance,
Uriel

Answer (score 5):

Add this

```
<style
name="CustomTheme"
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
.
.
.
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/TabBar</item>
</style>
```

And then

```
<style name="TabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">/** Whatever color you want, like #ffff00 **/</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase, it may help somebody

This below worked for me

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.MyActionBarTab</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyActionBarTabText</item>

    </style>


<style name="Theme.MyActionBarTab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/gray_mask</item>

    </style>


<style name="Theme.MyActionBarTabText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/size_28</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>

    </style>
```